# Ios - Android suggestion needed

Tags: android, ios, iphone, jailbreak, mdm

I devloped a MDM kind of application using device administartor in android(locking , disabling camera , wipe data etc..) and also my android app will try to fix wifi & bluetooth problems and killing process and getting location of device from desktop (if device lost) meny other. everything is going well,

Now I recently started working similar app in ios, give me some Idea to develop such kind of application in ios

1: Is it possible to access and modify wifi & bluettoth info in ios as free as android allows(checking flight mode status)

2: Any toolkit or 3rd party tools availabale to implement same kinf of MDM features in android or atleast some of them in IOS

3: Is it possible to get the list of apps installed in Ios Device

4: How maas360,citrix and few other able to make device administartive apps in IOS

5: Is it possible to make such kind of apps with out jail break

**NOTE: I am not going to publish this application in IOS Store**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it make sense to break it down to separate questions, because each person may have answer to one or two of them of top of his head, but not other.

First of all, there is a well known MDM protocol which allow you to manage iOS device. If you can a documentation for it out of your Enterprise Developer program or some pieces of it out of reverse engineered document - https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf

However, you should be aware this is a protocol between a client and a server (meaning that it's not an administrative app, but rather administrative server which will send commands to a client)

Answering some of your questions:

2) Wipe, Lock and disabling camera exist in this MDM protocol. I am not sure what does it mean fixing WiFi and BT problems (most likely you won't find it in such a protocol)

3) This protocol allows to get a list of installed applications on a device.

4) Most of MDM providers have MDM server which does 90% of functionality of them and the rest is done using some mix of app wrapping, network compliance, interception of other protocols and so on.

5) No.

Additional to these. I think you need to break apart questions like: 
"How can I do X on a jailbroken iOS device". This way you will be able to build an app which will provide some additional functionality on top of MDM protocol.

Comment: no. you don't need to jailbreak a device. it's legitimate protocol. however, you will need access to enterprise develop program.

Comment: victor you mean that MDM providers has made seperate protocols or they also using IOS inbuilt MDM feature and for communication they created their own servers..

Comment: That's exactly correct. There is inbuilt MDM agent which is configured using installation of MDM profile and as soon as it's configured, it operates in the background (most of the time without any interaction with a user)

Comment: Thank you very much victor , will apple prove any document to build such kind of apps..

Comment: Yes. Apple provides very good document (100 pages) about it. It's somewhere under enterprise developer program.